# problem when compile .docx file from codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, webserver, docx, php-ziparchive

i have this simple code that generate a new .docx file from a sample with some "token" to modify 
this code work in a local MAMP webserver

```
      $template_file_name = 'template2.docx';

      $rand_no = rand(111111, 999999);
      $fileName = "results_" . $rand_no . ".docx";

      $folder   = "results";
      $full_path = $folder . '/' . $fileName;
      echo $full_path;
      try
        {
            if (!file_exists($folder))
            {
                mkdir($folder);
            }

            //Copy the Template file to the Result Directory
            copy($template_file_name, $full_path);

            // add calss Zip Archive
            $zip_val = new ZipArchive;

            //Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
            if($zip_val->open($full_path) == true)
            {
                // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
                // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.

                $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
                $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);

                $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');

                // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
                $message = str_replace("token1", "text to replace",       $message);

                //Replace the content with the new content created above.
                $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
                $zip_val->close();
            }
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('file creato');</script>";
        }
        catch (Exception $exc)
        {
            $error_message =  "Error creating the Word Document";
            var_dump($exc);
        }
```

in online webserver despite the file and folder are 777 privileges ,the file was created but without my text to replace

in codeigniter i get this error:

```
$message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);
```

[image]

```
$zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
```

[image]

```
$zip_val->close();
```

[image]

anyone can help me ?
the stranger thigs are that in webserver in local work without problem, on webserver online doesnt work

i hope in your answer
thanks a lot

Comment: maybe ZipArchive class/library was not uploaded to server?

Comment: @Vickel what can i do to verify this ?